# Expand jQuery UI Dialog with Popover

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

I have a table in a jQuery UI Dialog that is filled with various data.  When the link "Select Code..." is clicked a [Twitter Bootstrap Popover](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers) appears.  The problem is that when the popover appears it is too big to fit inside the boundaries of the jQuery UI Dialog (see image).  A scrollbar appears and I can scroll to see the rest but I'm wondering how I can just dynamically expand the Dialog to display the entire popover.  Then, when the popover is removed, by re-clicking the link, I would like the Dialog to re-size back to its original height.

The `Work Orders` is a jQuery UI Dialog.  It is on top of a regular HTML page.  The `Select a code for this Work Order` is a Twitter Bootstrap Popover.  So, the image below shows 1 popover on top of 1 dialog on top of an HTML page.

Here is a simple jsFiddle recreation of the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/AaronSalazar/aa7Jr/

[image]

```
$("#workOrdersModal").dialog({ 
    title: "Work Orders", 
    width: 1000, 
    closeOnEscape: false, 
    draggable: true, 
    resizable: true, 
    modal: true, 
    autoOpen: false 
});
```

Comment: From your screenshot, it looks like the table (and popover) live in another type of popover; is this the case? If so, have you tried using an `overflow: auto` style rule on that first element? You may have to size the first element properly using JS (or change your popover to be a left or right side variant).

Comment: The "Work Orders" is a jQuery UI Dialog.  It is on top of just a regular HTML page.  The "Select a code for this Work Order" is a Twitter Bootstrap Popover.  So, 1 HTML page, 1 dialog and 1 popover.  Thank you for your question.  I'm never sure if I'm being clear enough.

Comment: Would it be possible to create a test case for this on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or is there too much involved?

Comment: good idea @JonahBishop, I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Here is a simple recreation of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/AaronSalazar/aa7Jr/